# Possible to drive Waveshare E-ink without driver hat?

Tags: spi

I bought and E-Ink display from waveshare and it came with such a “driver hat”: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/E-Paper_Driver_HAT#Display_Config_Switch

I am wondering what exactly is the role of this component? Why can’t I directly connect the cables from the display to the GIPO pins and drive the display without the driver hat - given the right software?

(I am also happy to get a pointer to a better forum to ask in if this here isn’t the right place.)

Comment: Have you completed the steps in the "Working With Arduino" section: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/E-Paper_Driver_HAT#Working_with_Arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need the hat, or something equivalent. Turn it over. You see all those components? They exist to generate the right voltages for the ePaper display. Without those it won't work.

Sure, you can recreate it from [the schematic](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/8/87/E-Paper-Driver-HAT-Schematic.pdf), but why bother when you have it already?

Comment: I think i was hoping that it could be emulated in software. Of course I assumed that it was not possible, but i was wondering WHY not.